# Integral affine functions without common factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Let $f_1$, $\ldots$, $f_m \colon \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}$ affine functions ( an affine function $f$ is of the form $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j + b $, with $a_j$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}$), such that for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ we have

$$\operatorname{gcd} (f_1(x), \ldots, f_m(x) ) = 1$$

Then there exist $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m) \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i f_i = 1$$

Notes:

1. The converse is clear.
2. Here is some a [particular case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453613/proving-that-given-fraction-is-irreducible) of this. Since all of the problems use the same idea of a linear combination, one is lead to believe that this is the underlying reason in general.
3. It works for $A$ a PID rather than $\mathbb{Z}$.  For $A = k$ a field, it is an earlier posted [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740365/affine-functions-without-common-zeroes) .
4. One could ask if it works or not for other rings, interesting in itself

Any feedback would be appreciated!

$\bf{Added:}$

The problem as stated is in fact Wrong. However, there are some cases where it seems to hold.   For now, I will add the extra hypothesis that every $f_i$ has its coefficients relatively prime ( that is, it is not divisible by another integral affine function).

Comment: What do you mean by $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_if_i\equiv 1$?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak: Oh, I mean identical $1$. But since it could be confused with congruence, I will write $=1$. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Is the constant $b$ meant to be $b_j$? And do you assume $gcd(a_i, b_j)=1$ as well as $gcd(a_i,a_j)=1$ for every pair?

Comment: @aerile: I mean that each $f_j$ is not an integral multiple of another integral form ( except $\pm$)

Comment: It seems that case such as $f_1=4x+1,f_2=4x+3$ or $f_1=3, f_2=3x+2$ should be excluded. (The first sentence of my previous comment was mistake.)

Comment: @aerile: Yes, I see... it seems the whole question is in fact wrong as stated.  I should just delete it